# Is there a way to create Azure AD application using Azure powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I looked for multiple solutions but could not find a proper solution for the creation of Azure AD application using PowerShell. I'm not looking to create an Azure AD itself but an application inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it through PowerShell. Please look at `New-AzureADApplication` Cmdlet: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986794.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But after using the command I don't see the application listed in my Active Directory's application tab. Also there is no parameter to relate it to my Active directory.

Comment: Here I'm talking about application tab in my Active directory on Azure portal

Comment: Do take a look here for an example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/

Comment: Thanks but the solution in the url did not show the created application on the Azure portal under my AD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Azure ARM commandlets:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757692.aspx

You should look specifically at:

New-AzureADApplication - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603747.aspx

New-AzureADServicePrincipal - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603780.aspx

Here's an example of how you'd run them:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication –DisplayName "My App" –  HomePage "http://myapp" –IdentifierUris "http://myapp"
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal –ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
```

Note that the "classic" Azure Portal (manage.windowsazure.com) only shows "Service Principals" in the Applications tab. So if you only create the AD Application without creating the Service Principal, you won't see an entry in the portal.

You can find more info about Application Principals and Service Principals here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-objects/

Key points from that article: Application object: This object represents a definition for your app. You can find a detailed description of its properties in the Application Object section below.

ServicePrincipal object: This object represents an instance of your app in your directory tenant. You can apply policies to ServicePrincipal objects, including assigning permissions to the ServicePrincipal that allow the app to read your tenant’s directory data. Whenever you change your Application object, the changes are also applied to the associated ServicePrincipal object in your tenant.